# Submit Job to Azure HDInsight Remotely

Tags: java, azure, apache-spark, hadoop-yarn, azure-hdinsight

I have an Azure HDInsight Spark cluster set up. I'd like to send a job remotely to my cluster:

```
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaSparkContext;
import org.apache.spark.api.java.JavaRDD;
import org.apache.spark.SparkConf;

public class App 
{
    public static void main( String[] args )
    {
        SparkConf conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("App").setMaster("spark://12.34.56.78:7077");
        JavaSparkContext sc = new JavaSparkContext(conf);
    }
}
```

The cluster was created in yarn mode. The master for the Spark workers is "yarn-client". It would've been desirable to connect directly to a hostname or an IP address.

What would be a good way to go about this?

Comment: hey did u get any solution for this?

Answer (score 0):

you cannot do this from JAVA program, please refer this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/hdinsight/hadoop/submit-apache-hadoop-jobs-programmatically

Comment: This is a borderline [link-only answer](//meta.stackexchange.com/q/8231). You should expand your answer to include as much information here, and use the link only for reference.

Answer (score -1):

Answered for the other way of submitting job in your comment, you can try to use the REST API `Batch Job` for HDInsight Spark, please refer to the reference https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/hdinsightspark/hdinsight-spark-batch-job to know it.

Comment: This is still using LIVY.